# Implement $Filter contains() using Olingo odata in java

Tags: java, rest, maven, odata, olingo

I'm trying to utilize olingo odata 4 library to implement $filter and specifically contains() logic.
We have already implemented our rest APIs with the database. So we don't want to use any other features that olingo odata4 library provides.

for example below is my endpoint
https:localhost:8095/myapi/Products?$filter=contains(name,'myProductName')

$filter is the query parameter and I can fetch contains(name,'myProductName') from that.

All I need to do is verify that it is contains() function and returns a Map with Key = name and Value = myProductName

I am stuck at UriInfo part, I don't have edm or odata.

We might add more filter functions that's why our requirement is to use olingo odata4 library.

I looked at so many documentations and there are no tutorials that I found useful for my requirement.

Please let me know if there are good documentations that I can follow or any further discussions will be helpful.

Thanks in advance!